# calculating Overtime on the basis of hours

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two tables. One is named *tbl_workers* and other is *tbl_attendance*. 
In *tbl_worker*, I have recorded the salary of the worker. 
And in *tbl_attendance*, I have recorded the overtime he did on the particular day. 
Now, what I want is first to generate the per hour wage for the worker.
By dividing salary by 31 and then dividing the result by 9, as 9 hour is the normal working day of the office. 
By doing this, I have in hand the per hour rate of the worker. 
Now, what I want is to multiply each row (OT is the name of the column) of *tbl_attendence* with the per hour rate of the worker and store it in another column named *overtime_rate*. what I have done so far is :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TIMBERTRENDZ-PC\NEWSERVER;Initial Catalog=trendz;user id=sa;Password=Letmein3#;Trusted_connection=False");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select worker_salary from tbl_workers where worker_id='"+textBox1.Text +"'",con);
        int salary = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        salary = salary/31;
        salary = salary / 9;
        label1.Text = Convert.ToString(salary);
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select ot from tbl_attendence where worker_id='"+textBox1.Text + "'",con);
        int ot = (int)cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
        ot = ot / 60;
        salary = salary * ot;
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("update tbl_attendence set overtime_rate='"+salary +"' where worker_id='"+textBox1+ "'",con);
        /**int i = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        label2.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
        **/
```

But this is storing same amount in all the columns which match the worker id.

Comment: Lets hope nobody thinks their worker_id is `0';DROP TABLE tbl_workers--` [reference](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: In your update command, you probably also need to filter by date; e.g. where worker_id = id and date = some_date. Otherwise, your query will update every OT entry for that worker for all of their attendance.

Comment: So they work 9 hours per day *every* day of the month, including weekends? (And make up extra hours in short months, presumably). Is there a reason to *store* this result, when it can be recalculated by e.g. a view and not be wrong, even after corrections to the base rows?

Comment: Could you state what is your problem?

Comment: Also, you make a round trip for calculating overtime for each and every employee?

Comment: @Jamiec Hey that's my worker id. I had it changed from `0'DROP TABLE tbl_students` when I left school.

Answer (score 1):

OK I need an explanation, firstly why are you doing this using ADO.Net when it could be done as a single update in the DB, secondly is there a reason you need the value saved in the db as this opens yourself up for data to become out of sync when the employees Salary is changed you need to make sure that the Overtime Value is also updated.

```
Select ((worker_salary / 31) / 9) * (ot / 60) 
from tbl_attendence as a 
inner join tbl_workers as w on w.worker_id = a.worker_id
where worker_id=
```

This query will get you your OT rate based on your calculations above. To then update the overtime_rate field in the tbl_attendance table you can run

```
update tbl_attendence set overtime_rate= 
Select ((worker_salary / 31) / 9) * (ot / 60) )  
from tbl_attendence as a 
inner join tbl_workers as w on w.worker_id = a.worker_id
```

This will update all workers Overtime rates for you. No need to use C#, ADO, it just lets SQL Server do its job. Verify the SQL before you run it as I typed it free hand not checked the brackets etc.

Hope this helps.

Jason

Edit:

To help you understand how this query works a bit further I have made sure to include the table names on the column names. The query would have worked anyway as long as the columns didn't exist in both tables.

```
update tbl_attendence set overtime_rate= 
Select ((w.worker_salary / 31) / 9) * (a.ot / 60) )  
from tbl_attendence as a 
inner join tbl_workers as w on w.worker_id = a.worker_id
```

Comment: I am not very good in sql and I liked your query and I can understand that it will update but now the problem is you wrote this query assuming that worker_salary and ot both columns are in same table however both of them are in different table. worker_salary is in tbl_workers and ot is in tbl_attendence I hope you can help me out here